# Могут ли объекты класса генерироваться без имени(или с рандомно присвоенным машиной). И как в таком случае его узнать

Tags: python, классы

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
    def about(self):
        return self.name + ' ' + self.surname

men = []
for i in range(5):
    one = input("enter person ")
    one = one.split()
    men.append(Person(one[0], one[1]))
for i in men:
    print(i.about())
```

Каждая строка списка является объектом класса(или точнее ссылается на объект класса, созданный конструктором) правильно?причем без заданного имени. В таком случае как я могу получить имя конкретного объекта в списке (например по значению одного из параметров(name)?

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под именем объекта? Лично мне совсем непонятна Ваша формулировка вопроса. Будет очень хорошо, если Вы приведёте пример желаемого вывода.

Comment: ну например:
class human:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
sasha = human()
print (sasha)
дает объект <__main__.sasa object at 0x000001D60E407128>
Пример с конструктором выше дает целый список объектов, однако к ним не обратиться по присвоенному имени, как к объекту класса human, sasha.
Тогда как я могу вызвать определенный объект из списка или присвоить ему имя?
Как-нибудь вроде
ad = (men [1])
print(ad.about())

Comment: @Nachalniy именно так и можете (`print(men[1].about())`), попробуйте, должно работать

Comment: я конечно могу таким образом обратиться к объекту из списка print((men [1]).about()) но как присвоить имя не знаю

Comment: в любом случае спс за ответ

Comment: В некотором смысле, `men[1]`  и есть его имя, а зачем оно нужно Вам? Также, у каждого объёкта есть `id` (`id(men[1])` вернёт `id` для `men[1]`), и эти `id` уникальные